# How to apply weight to Google heatmap?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, json, heat-map

I am trying to plot a Google heatmap based on the JSON objects returned. Here is my JavaScript:

```
function getHeatMap() {
 heatLayer = new HeatmapLayer({
config: {
    "useLocalMaximum": true,
    "radius": 40,
    "gradient": {
        0.45: "rgb(000,000,255)",
        0.55: "rgb(000,255,255)",
        0.65: "rgb(000,255,000)",
        0.95: "rgb(255,255,000)",
        1.00: "rgb(255,000,000)"
    }
},
"map": map,
"domNodeId": "heatLayer",
"opacity": 0.85
});

$.ajax({
url: "index.aspx/getBusCommuter",
type: "POST",
data: "",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
    $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
        var coordXicon = jsondata.BusStopX;
        var coordYicon = jsondata.BusStopY;
        var commuterAmt = jsondata.CommuterAmt;
        var data = [
   {
       attributes: {},
       geometry: {
           spatialReference: { wkid: 102100 },
           type: "point",
           x: coordXicon,
           y: coordYicon,
           weight: commuterAmt
       }
   }
        ];

        heatLayer.setData(data);

    });
    map.addLayer(heatLayer);
},
error: function (request, state, errors) {
}
});
}
```

Basically I tried to set the heat weight by commuterAmt so that it is not just simply plot a heat at each coordinates that I declared. However, it does not work. For every point on the map, it just simply plot a heat without taking account into the commuterAmt.

[image]

Attached image shows the heat plotted on each bus stop. Although each bus stop has different commuterAmt but the heat seems all the same.

I wonder is there any alternate way to set the weight as the heatmap used in Google Maps.

Comment: @PolyGeo Any guides?

Comment: On this one I can only help with applying tags and edits to try and bring it to the attention of those most likely to be able to help.

Comment: Any guides? Or is there any alternate way to set up my heatmap?

Comment: @PolyGeo Hello I figured out how to set the weight already. It's called count for Esri and you can set it in the attributes. Thanks for the helps! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I just set a count attributes as the following codes:

```
             data.push(
                {
                    attributes: {count:commuterAmt},
                    geometry: {
                        spatialReference: { wkid: 102100 },
                        type: "point",
                        x: coordXicon,
                        y: coordYicon
                    }
                }
           );
```